# Consumir Web Service en una aplicación MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, webservice

estoy intentando consumir un web service en una aplicación MVC, ya implemente el Service Reference, ahora lo que quiero es hacer un controlar que reciba una lista y poder mostrarla en una vista

Este es el **WebMethod** en el Web Service que me selecciona de la base de datos y guarda la información en una lista

```
public void HelloWorld()
    {
        var Lista = new List<Atributos>();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cnn))
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ASIGNATURA", con);
            con.Open();
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var hambre = new Atributos
                {
                    iD = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                    Nombre = dr[1].ToString(),
                    Credito = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString())

                };
                Lista.Add(hambre);
            }
        }
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(Lista));
    }
```

En el HomeController hice la instancia de el Service References mas ya después de eso no se que mas debería de hacer.

E hice una vista que encontre el coding en internet y lo acomode a como debería de ser el mío, es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como poder usarlo en el Controller? Y si este código que encontré y modifique podría funcionar.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que estas confundido, una cosa es un asmx y otra distinta es un action en un controller de asp.net mvc, en tu caso estas mezclando todo. Ese metodo HelloWorld() lo defines dentro de HomeController o esta en un asmx ?

Comment: Esta en el asma. Disculpa, estoy aprendiendo recién.

Gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 2):

Se supone que desde la view el `$.ajax` lo tienes que haces al controller no al servicio

Podris implementar todo sin necesidad de ningun servicio, algo como ser

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HelloWorld()
    {
        var Lista = new List<Atributos>();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cnn))
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ASIGNATURA", con);
            con.Open();
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var hambre = new Atributos
                {
                    iD = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                    Nombre = dr[1].ToString(),
                    Credito = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString())

                };
                Lista.Add(hambre);
            }
        }

        return Json(Lista);
    }
}
```

entonces desde la view usas el $.ajax invocando ese action

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: '/Home/HelloWorld', 
    success: function (result) {  
        alert(result);  
    },  
    error: function (xhr) {  
        console.log(xhr.responseText);  
        alert("Error has occurred..");  
    }  
});
```

valida que la url apunta al action del controller, no necesitas ninguna servicio asmx

[JsonResult Type in MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/jsonresult-type-in-mvc/)

Comment: Comprendo, el problema es que en el proyecto en el cual estoy trabajando una de las especificaciones es utilizar asmx :(

Comment: no se que especifica el proyecto, pero al menos lo que defienes no es correcto y mezclas conceptos